# How to go about grabbing data from firebase for use across every class in my app - swift ios development

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, structure

When the app loads, I need the family and name for the current user that is logged in to be stored in a variable that can be accessed by every class and view controller in my app. Currently, everytime i need to access, say, the name in a different class I have to download a snapshot again. I want it so i only have to download a snapshot that contains essential user data that can be used across the whole app.

It was recommended I make a User class and store the data in here, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks

Database Structure:

[image: database screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right path. I ran into this same issue, but you can store this data as cached data or even store it in core data if you want. Hope this pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: Don't know if this is a good idea / bad practice. I have decided to store the essential user data in UserDefaults. I can then read and write to this as need be.

Comment: Now I have just recently used User defaults, but according to Apples documentation you should be using user defaults for settings in an app like font color a user prefers. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: I actually have been playing around and ended up creating a new swift file that contains a struct with the users data in. Then i can just edit and obtain this from every class, seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class called `UserManager` and save the User instance inside it as `currentUser` when u first load the user from firebase. Then you can call it from anywhere in the app using `UserManager.sharedInstance.currentUser` as follows:

```
class User {

    var userId: String?

    init(_ userId: String) {
        self.userId = userId
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.userId ?? ""
    }
}

class FirebaseManager {
    class func login(_ userId:String) -> User {
        // Put the code that loads the user from firebase here
        return User(userId)
    }
}
class UserManager {
    static let sharedInstance = UserManager()
    var currentUser:User?
    func loadUser(_ userId:String) {
        self.currentUser = FirebaseManager.login(userId)
    }
}

UserManager.sharedInstance.loadUser("firebase_user_id")

print(UserManager.sharedInstance.currentUser?.description ?? "")
```

Now, when you want to load the user from firebase when the app launches just call

```
UserManager.sharedInstance.loadUser(userId)
```

Then, anywhere in the app when u want to get the currentUser just call

```
UserManager.sharedInstance.currentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Appdelegate for such purpose You can save your array , any string if you like in appDelegate and it don't even pit load on memory

use steps as below

1) make some Variables in Appdelegate like below for array and a name string for logged user

```
var nameString = String() //String

var userArray = [String:AnyObject]() //Array from Firebase
```

2) now just put Data to these variables by creating a Object for appdelgate As below in Source Controller

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

self.appDelegate.userArray = familyArray //[String: Anyobject] Just put all your array in appDel.

self.appDelegate.nameString = LoggesUserName //Pass a string value in first load of screen
```

3) now time to use the saved values [ DestinationView Controller]

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

let userArray: [String:AnyObject] = self.appDelegate.userArray
```

and get your values anyWhere you want